# pass query table to another function in mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i got a problem here and i hope someone can assist me to solve my problem. the problem is: im using c# and mvc. i want to pass db table to another function. i dont know how to solve this.. hope someone out there can help me

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var viewModel = db.test.ToList()
        ExportExcel(viewModel); //pass current table to excel to export
        return View(viewModel);
    }

//export to excel
public ActionResult ExportExcel(xxxx viewModel)
    {
        var grid = new GridView();
        grid.DataSource = from p in viewModel
                          select new
                          {
                              Name = p.name,
                              No = p.staffno
                          };
        grid.DataBind();

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=MyExcelFile.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        grid.RenderControl(htw);

        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

        return View("MyView");
    }
```

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?  What isn't working?

Comment: i want to pass the viewModel  in Index() to ExportExcel().. but i dont know how to call it.. see ExportExcel with the 'xxxx'

Comment: Change xxxx to the type of `viewModel` ?

Comment: yup.. what should i use? tried IEnumerable, Datatype...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `View("viewName")` returns a View Result, you can call it directly and return it from your Index method, providing that you pass your viewModel to your `ExportExcel` method.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = db.test.ToList()
    var viewResult = ExportExcel(viewModel);
    return viewResult;
}

//export to excel
public ActionResult ExportExcel(List<test> viewModel)
{
    var grid = new GridView();
    grid.DataSource = from p in viewModel
                      select new
                      {
                          Name = p.name,
                          No = p.staffno
                      };
    grid.DataBind();

    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=MyExcelFile.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

    Response.Charset = "";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    grid.RenderControl(htw);

    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();

    return View("MyView");
}
```

Comment: its said The type or namespace name 'test' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @achimet no problem.  That was simply a best guess as to what your model might be.  If you update your question I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Change the ExportExcel function return type into bool or void and change the parameter into viewmodel instead of xxxx..
Probably you can move that code to some utility class.

Comment: public void ExportExcel(viewmodel viewModel) ??

Comment: sorry.. can u explain more detail

i got this error:
The type or namespace name 'viewModel' could not be found

Answer (score 0):

Assuming viewModel is a System.Data.DataTable:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Dummy data
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
        var row = dt.NewRow();
        row[0] = 4;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);

        ExportExcel(dt);
        return View();
    }
```

In your export method change the paprameter type to DataTable:

```
    public EmptyResult ExportExcel(DataTable test)
    {
        var grid = new GridView();

        grid.DataSource = test;
        grid.DataBind();
       ... your existing code 
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```